# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent with Chai and Mocha

Tags: express, mocha.js, chai

I am testing with Mocha and Chai with Express, but I keep on getting this error when testing two error handling routes. The test still passes, but I still get the error message. Not sure how to handle it in the test

```
describe.only('allYears services', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await db.sequelize.sync({force: true, logging: false});
  });

  it('should response with 400 when missing gaugeId or classId', async () => {
    await chai
      .request(app)
      .post('/api/allyears/getBoxPlotAttributes')
      .send({metric: 'average'})
      .catch(err => {
        assert.equal(err.response.status, 400);
      });
  });

  it('should response with 400 when missing metric', async () => {
    await chai
      .request(app)
      .post('/api/allyears/getBoxPlotAttributes')
      .send({gaugeId: 123456})
      .catch(err => {
        assert.equal(err.response.status, 400);
      });
  });
});
```

I get the following error message:

> (node:95031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: could you share your source file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the eg. `res.status(200).send({ something });`

This would give you the error when testing with Mocha + Chai:

```
if (isInvalid(req)) {
  res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'invalid request' });
}
```

This works normally:

```
if (isInvalid(req)) {
  return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'invalid request' });
}
```